# .\gradlew run -t -> all subprojects, watch all changes and rebuild does not work

Tags: gradle, micronaut, hot-reload, multi-project, continuous-build

currently I'm working on a java project which is built by gradle. The project consists of an web-api micronaut subproject and some library subprojects. See output

**.\gradlew -q projects**

```
Root project 'mbtn_be'
+--- Project ':app'
+--- Project ':db'
+--- Project ':model'
+--- Project ':repository'
\--- Project ':service'
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'mbtn_be'

include 'service', 'db', 'model', 'app', 'repository'
```

In case of development I execute the project with `.\gradlew run -t`. If I change something in the app (web-api by micronaut) gradle rebuilds instantly the code.

But if I change something in the other subprojects the changes won't built again. It seems that only 'app' is built on changes.

I've googled around to find a solution without luck.

Do you have an idea how to build all subprojects on changes?

Thanks a lot :)

Sebastian

Comment: Do you have `run` task in all those subprojects? `.\gradlew :db:tasks | grep "run -"`

Comment: All other projects are libraries. All libraries have no main method. So all have no run task, except 'app'

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: The Gradle Version is actually: 7.6

Comment: Have you tried with `build` instead of `run` to discard that the issue is because of the `run` usage?

Answer (score 1):

Micronaut's file watching only works in the project where the `run` task is defined, that is to say in your `app` project. This is a limitation of the Micronaut Gradle plugin right now.